# Is Qt Quick mature enough for large desktop applications?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

I'm planning to write a program that is especially designed for tablets, the main platform is MeeGo (because I'm taking a contest).

Edited:

My program has following needs:

1. heavy C++ usage to deal with networking and low-level optimization
2. dynamically generate contents (like what Flipboard app did)
3. completely customized GUI

and I found Qt Quick has the following shortcomings:

1. integrating with C++ is not very easy now
2. it is hard to express complex logic
3. sometimes very slow. For example, when showing a list of resized images, it will be rather slow because of resizing same images again and agian. It's not Qt Quick's fault, but it's very difficult to be fixed.

So can Qt Quick meet my needs?

Comment: Which were the important components that Qt lacks again?

Comment: I have edited my question, hoping it's better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have specific expertise in QtQuick, though I was evaluating it for our app last year.  It's come on a long way since then and in particular it's much easier to embed QtQuick widgets within a native app or native widgets within a QtQuick app.  Whether it's worth adopting will depend on the requirements of your app -- if it's a very GUI-rich app with clean encapsulations to the underlying logic then it may be worthwhile.  If the UI is closely coupled to the program logic then maybe a native app is better, perhaps using QtQuick components for the more dynamic parts of the interface.

I would suggest building a simple prototype to see if it does meet your requirements before making the final decision either way.

Answer (score 4):

You have a prefect question to ask. QtQuick was originally developed for Qt on mobile devices, and now Qt devs are bringing it to the desktop also. The process is not yet complete however with Qt5 (lets hope), QtQuick will be, de jure, used to write Qt GUI.